# Setting a static outbound / source IP address on Google Compute Engine

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

I set up a static External IP address for a Google Compute Engine VM Instance and when I SSH into the machine, my outbound requests (e.g. curl canhazip.com) originate from the static External IP, but when I launch the Google Cloud Shell from within the console or when I deploy an app (e.g. a Python app via gcloud app deploy, the IP address is different. Any ideas on how to make this consistent? Do I need to specify something in the app.yaml? In other words, if I wanted to deploy a Python app that looked like this:

```
import requests

print('requesting...')
res = requests.get("http://ip.jsontest.com/")
print(res.text)
```

How would I configure it to always return the same static External IP I already set up?

Answer (score 1):

Both Cloud Shell as well as App Engine do not have direct network access.

- For Cloud Shell, there are [limitations to network access](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#outgoing_connections). Since Cloud Shell is an [ephemeral instance](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#virtual_machine_instance), you do not have further control over things like IP addresses used.
- App Engine Standard runs a sandboxed environment without network access. Applications have to use either the [Sockets or URLFetch API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#sockets) to make external requests. The python runtime patches sockets and urllib so that most python code can use these APIs without further modification.

If you need a consistent source IP address for outgoing connections, you're likely looking for an [egress NAT gateway](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/special-configurations#natgateway). This setup will however also not be usable from Cloud Shell or App Engine Standard.